# Class changing data members of other class

Tags: c++, class

I have two classes `Maxsegtree` and `Minsegtree` in my C++ program .

Class `Maxsegtree` has 2 private data members `P` and `Q` with memory dynamically allocated at instance creation.

Class `Minsegtree` has similar 2 data members `A` and `B`.

When I am calling a member function of class `Minsegtree` the values of data member of `Maxsegtree` `A` are getting changed.

[This is the ideone link to the program.](http://ideone.com/9zDgU0)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Maxsegtree
{
    int* P;
    int* Q;
public:
    Maxsegtree(int N)
    {
        P = new int[N];
        Q = new int[2 * N];
    }

    ~Maxsegtree()
    {
        delete[] P;
        delete[] Q;
    }

    int getP(int i)
    {
        return P[i];
    }

    void setP(int i, int x)
    {
        P[i] = x;
    }

    void build_tree(int node, int l, int r)
    {
        if (l == r)
            Q[node] = l;
        else
        {
            build_tree(node * 2, l, (l + r) / 2);
            build_tree(node * 2 + 1, (l + r) / 2 + 1, r);
            if (P[Q[2 * node]] > P[Q[2 * node + 1]])
                Q[node] = Q[2 * node];
            else
                Q[node] = Q[2 * node + 1];
        }
    }
};

class Minsegtree
{
    int* A;
    int* B;
public:
    Minsegtree(int N)
    {
        A = new int[N];
        B = new int[2 * N];
    }

    ~Minsegtree()
    {
        delete[] A;
        delete[] B;
    }

    int getA(int i)
    {
        return A[i];
    }

    void setA(int i, int x)
    {
        A[i] = x;
    }

    void build_mintree(int node, int l, int r)
    {
        if (l == r)
            B[node] = l;
        else
        {
            build_mintree(node * 2, l, (l + r) / 2);
            build_mintree(node * 2 + 1, (l + r) / 2 + 1, r);
            if (A[B[2 * node]] <= A[B[2 * node + 1]])
                B[node] = B[2 * node];
            else
                B[node] = B[2 * node + 1];
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    int n;
    int x;
    cin >> n;
    Minsegtree mint(n);
    Maxsegtree maxt(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> x;
        mint.setA(i, x);
        maxt.setP(i, x);
    }
    cout << "Before function is called" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << maxt.getP(i) << " ";
    cout << endl;
    mint.build_mintree(1, 0, n - 1);
    cout << "After function is called" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << maxt.getP(i) << " ";
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Could somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You should follow the rule of three in your classes; if you define one of the destructor, copy constructor, or copy assignment operator, you should define all three. As it stands now, the compiler-generated copy constructor and copy assignment operator won't know to copy the allocations of the pointers, so when a copy is destructed it will delete the memory being used by the object from which it was copied. This invokes undefined behavior. You may be making copies accidentally, causing this problem. (Or just use `std::vector<int>` instead of managing your own pointers.)

Comment: @cdhowie Thanks for the quick reply. Using vector seems good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you are accessing the array outside of the limits.

Add checks by using `std::vector` instead of raw pointer and by using `.at()` instead of `[]` for accessing. Code like:

```
B[node] = l;
```

for example become

```
B.at(node) = l;
```

This way if you access outside the limits an `std::out_of_range` exception will be thrown.

Using `vector`s instead of manually allocated arrays will also take care about deallocation and proper implementation of copy constructor and assignment in case you end up using them.

Comment: No, array accesses are inside the limit. The problem was due to destructor . I've deleted the destructor and used vector. Correct version [link] http://ideone.com/gVIzHc [link]

Comment: No. Array access are outside the limits; I tried with input 10 + 1 10 2 9 3 8 4 7 5 6 and `.at` calls did throw the out of range exception as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing out of range memory locations in Minsegtree::build_mintree. Check it manually or use valgrind, a good place to [start](http://maintainablecode.logdown.com/posts/245425-valgrind-is-not-a-leak-checker).

Answer (score 1):

In `build_mintree`, value of `node` is likely to exceed `2*N` if `N` is not a power of 2 (e.g. for `n=18` it goes above 40), because the tree becomes sparse.